# Adjust traveling sine wave to match rotating point on circle

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want the icosphere to be rotating on the circle, while the sine wave moves on the x axis, so that the icosphere is on it. The wave moves according to `|sine(x)|` or absolute of sine

[image]

[image]

Comment: can u add a link how the animation should look like?

Comment: do you mean like that? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDQEO.gif

Comment: Only the first 2 steps ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

[image]

I first thought you want the circle to just move on the sinusoide, but then realized you want the circle to stay on x=0 and to move up and down on the moving sinusoide so I added the last transform...

[image]

Comment: Can you please give me a tutorial , on how to make a foto of GNode  e the git of the curves .